# VS2012 C# SQL database error - improperly installed?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012

On computer A my project is working fine, but on computer B I get a SQL exception:

> *A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - **Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified**)*

Every time I call the `CreateDatabse()` method (from `Database` class that inherits from `DataContext` class).

I already tried to reinstall the whole SQL Server - but the exception remained. I have SQL Server 2012 installed. List of my SQL related programs installed:

[image: List of my SQL-related programs installed]

If it makes any difference, computer A is working under win8 and computer B on win7.

Database is created by program code:

```
String FOLDER_PATH = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "ProgramName");
Directory.CreateDirectory(FOLDER_PATH);

String path = Path.Combine(FOLDER_PATH, "database.mdf");
Database db = new Database(path);

bool exists = db.DatabaseExists();

if (exists == false)
    db.CreateDatabase();

public class Database : DataContext
{
    public Table<Record> RecordTable;
    public Database(string connection) : base(connection) { }
}
```

edit: My problem is still unsolved. I've tried to reinstall MS SQL one more time, with no effect.

Comment: do you have the actual *database* on computer B?

Comment: @Thousand - that databe is created by by program. I'll add that code to original post.

Comment: Can you put your connection string here?

Comment: @DrTJ - done. But as I said before, that code works fine on another machine.

Comment: @gogowitczak: sometimes it works fine on the local machine, but about network services, maybe firewall or Anitvirus programs prevent your SQL services to work fine...

Comment: @DrTJ - I've disabled antivirus&firewall software and ran VS in admin mode - still same exception is thrown.

Comment: Have enabled remote access in SQL server configuration??

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when the connection string is not correctly configured or firewall on computer A is preventing SQLServer to work fine on the network...

Comment: It's offline program, so we don't care about firewall or network-related issues. And connection string seems fine to me.

Comment: If the database is attached in SQLServer on computer A, so it's not OFFLINE... you are facing a network database not a local...

Comment: No, you misunderstood me. On each computer, database is created locally. And they aren't connected. Each user shoud be able to create and use his own DB.

Comment: ok, so the only problem can be about `server name`
can you show me your connection string ?

Comment: I've added it to original post.

Comment: I know, but if `public Database(string connection) : base(connection) { }` is the constructor of your `Database` class, so how do you create new instances? you should pass a connection string to the constructor.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. I've read on MSDN that it's proper way of doing that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399420.aspx

Comment: Good, so you are passing the database path like this:  
`Database db = new Database(@"c:\database1.mdf");`
what are you passing instade of `@"c:\database1.mdf"`?

Comment: `String path` passed to `Database` contructor has value `"C:\\Users\\UserName\\AppData\\Roaming\\ProgramName\\database.mdf"`